# An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have create Database first MVC4 web application EF edmx updated from sql database it work fist time but after change database table  and update edmx by updated  model from database then occurs this error.

Comment: what's the inner exception? please provide more details. what you've provided doesn't help anyone.

Comment: System.data.EntityCommand Exception:{"An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details."}

Comment: and did you check the inner exception?

Comment: You need to provide more details. Also you may want to watch this video (or read descriptions below it): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem only by rebuild database connection from EF to SQLServer Database.

Comment: How did you do that?